# How to prevent a user from going back/forward when they are on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, navigation

I have a script that runs inside a frame of a different system (ie. phone system.) Every time a user clicks shift and scroll with their mouse, the page goes back and it caused an issue with the phone system.

I need to completely stop the user from navigating forward or backward as this page will be controlled by the phone system and should be open as long as the phone system in open.

To stop the navigation I have done this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function stop()
 {
     return false;
 }

 document.onmousewheel = stop;
 window.onbeforeunload = stop;

</script>
```

But this displays a message "Are you sure you want to leave this page?" The user will have to click on "Leave this page" or "Stay on this page" to continue.

However, if the user clicks "Leave this page" I will still run into the original issue.

Is there way I can completely stop the user from going back? 
Here are potential solutions that I an think of but can't apply any of them

1. Make the code clicks "Stay on this page" on the user's behalf. If I can always clicks "Stay on this page"
2. Disable the "Leave this page" button. Therefore, the use will have no other buttons to click but "Stay on this page".

Comment: Browser will not allow you to do either 1 or 2. Hence it is not possible at all.

Comment: Bindind a keypress event to your HTML document and using event.preventDefault() when these specific keys are pressed should work for you. Can you test this?

Comment: @lucasnadalutti  how do I do that?

Comment: I'll post it as an answer even though I'm not sure if this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you have jQuery loaded. I can't test this in your scenario so just tell me if this works for you.

```
$('html').keypress(function(event) {
    // 16 is shift's key code
    if (event.which === 16) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

This should prevent the shift key to do whatever its default behaviour in your browser is.